# javascript image swap keeps looping

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a image that changes automatically depending upon the date.  So I have a default image, then at a holiday, it changes automatically to a holiday themed image.  The code seems to work, but when you put it in a page, the code keeps looping.  Any help would be much appreciated.   Thanks in advance.

```
<img id="Logo" src="/images/default.png" alt="Default Image"   onload="logo(this)" />

function logo(img) {
var d = new Date();
var Today = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth();
var src;
if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 21 && Today <= 23)) {
src = "/images/holiday.png";
}  else {
src = "/images/default.png";
} 
img.src=src;
}
```

Comment: You have an `onload` event, and you keep changing the image source, so it will continually fire the `onload`. Just make that a function that runs once, targeting that element and you're golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function is set to run on the `load` event of the image. The function then swaps the `src` of the image, thus causing a new image to load, and so you get another `load` event occurring, which swaps the image source and so on.

Set your function to run on the `load` event of the `window` instead:

```js
// Set your function to run when the window is loaded
window.addEventListener("load", logo);

// Get your element reference
var img = document.getElementById("Logo");

// This is your callback function
function logo() {
  var d = new Date();
  var Today = d.getDate();
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src;
  if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 21 && Today <= 23)) {
    src = "/images/holiday.png";
  } else {
    src = "/images/default.png";
  } 
  img.src=src;
}
```

```html
<img id="Logo" src="/images/default.png" alt="Default Image">
```

But, really this is not a great approach because the image will only be swapped after the default image loads, so the user will see the default image briefly and then they will see it change to the desired image.  Instead, you should just set the initial source of the image dynamically so that only one image is ever loaded.

If you place your `<script>` element just prior to the closing `body` tag (`</body>`), the browser will have already parsed the `img` element into memory, but it won't have a `src` set for it yet, so the user won't see anything at that point. Then the script runs and sets the `src` to the right image. In the end, only one image is loaded and no event handlers need to be set up.

```html
<body>
  <img id="Logo" src="" alt="Correct Image">
  <script>
    // Just determine the appropriate source:
    var d = new Date();
    var Today = d.getDate();
    var Month = d.getMonth();
    var src;
    if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 21 && Today <= 23)) {
      src = "/images/holiday.png";
    } else {
      src = "/images/default.png";
    } 
    
    // And then set the image to it:
    document.getElementById("Logo").src = src;
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `onload` of your `img`, you cause `logo` to get called when an image is loaded, which loads a new image, which causes `logo` to get called, which...

So either you need to have `logo` not always change the image, or you want `logo` called under different circumstances.